# 8 - SQL error "String data, right truncated..." when creating/updating a node programmatically, but OK when inserting via the CLI. Why?

Tags: 8, nodes, database

When I attempt to programmatically update an event node, I get the error:

`SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'field_event_end_date_and_time_value'...`

For most date fields. If I insert the record(s) with the same information into MySQL directly via the CLI, it updates/inserts correctly. Anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

**Full error from logs:**

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String
>   data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column
>   'field_event_end_date_and_time_value' at row 1: INSERT INTO
>   {node__field_event_end_date_and_time} (entity_id, revision_id, bundle,
>   delta, langcode, field_event_end_date_and_time_value) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 7159 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 7750
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => events [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
>   2014-06-18CDT21:30:00 ) in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 770 of
>   /var/www/acg/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

**My queries:**

```
UPDATE node__field_event_end_date_and_time SET field_event_end_date_and_time_value = '2014-06-18CDT21:30:00' WHERE delta = 0 AND langcode = 'en' AND entity_i
d = 7159 AND deleted = 0;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO node__field_event_end_date_and_time (entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, langcode, field_event_end_date_and_time_value) VALUES(7159, 7750, '
events', 0, 'en', '2014-06-18CDT21:30:00');
```

work correctly through the CLI.

**Output of `show columns FROM node__field_event_end_date_and_time`**

```
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle                              | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted                             | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id                           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id                         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| langcode                            | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_event_end_date_and_time_value | varchar(20)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Does anyone see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI works because then you're not in strict mode and it just cuts the string off.

Your date format is wrong. It must be in the format defined by [`DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21datetime.module/constant/DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT/8.2.x)
 and converted to the correct timezone [`DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21datetime.module/constant/DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE/8.2.x).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I've selected this as the correct answer. Thanks for your help.